# Does iTunes 12 work with Mountain Lion?

Tags: itunes

I have iTunes 11.4 running on Mountain Lion 10.8.5.  The iTunes permissions are constantly in need of repair and I'm considering moving to iTunes 12.  Can anyone tell me if they're using it on Mountain Lion, and does it work well or are there problems.
Thanks!

Comment: Repair Disk Permissions can generate some spurious and ignorable errors, of which 3 are iTunes related. View the list here: http://support.apple.com/en-us/TS1448

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I administer a large number of Macs running 10.8.5 with iTunes 12 and have not had any reports of major problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes-**
It works on Lion and Yosemite , so I see no reason why it should not work on the OS versions in between those two.

The OS requirement can be found [here](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/).